# SQL Server Union performance improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image: Table Data Stucture]

This table has over 400k rows.

I am getting the values with a SQL Server function as below; actually I would like to get the last update record.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FncGetName] 
    (@Season VARCHAR(30),
     @NameCode VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(150)

    SET @Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Names.Name 
                 FROM
                     (SELECT
                          CASE 
                             WHEN Name1Unidecode IS NOT NULL 
                                THEN Name1Unidecode 
                                ELSE Name1 
                          END AS Name       
                      FROM
                          Persons
                      WHERE
                          Season IS NOT NULL
                          AND Season = @Season
                          AND Name1Code LIKE @NameCode + '%'
                      GROUP BY  
                          Name1, Name1Unidecode

                      UNION

                      SELECT
                          CASE 
                             WHEN Name2Unidecode IS NOT NULL 
                                THEN Name2Unidecode 
                                ELSE Name2 
                          END AS Name
                      FROM
                          Persons 
                      WHERE
                          Season IS NOT NULL
                          AND Season = @Season
                          AND Name2Code LIKE @NameCode + '%'
                      GROUP BY 
                          Name2, Name2Unidecode) AS Names
             )

    RETURN @Name
END
```

This is the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT 
    ID, ISNULL(dbo.FncGetName(Season , NameCode),ShortName) AS Name 
FROM 
    Table1
```

So is there any approach to improve the performance?

**EDITED**

I have created 2 Index for UNION's SELECT query as below and performance improved.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name1] ON [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Season] DESC,
    [Name1Code] DESC,
    [Name1 DESC,
    [Name1Unidecode] DESC
)


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name2] ON [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Season] DESC,
    [Name2Code] DESC,
    [Name2 DESC,
    [Name2Unidecode] DESC
)
```

Comment: Do you want the last updated record? You can just use row_number() over(partition by Name order by Update desc) and then select no 1, then you get each last updated name

Comment: Why there is no `order by`? Last record according to which ordering?

Comment: I have 2 name columns. If I need to get Luis record I must use UNION. Because of that this working slow.

Comment: GROUP BY but no aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use the following query instead of the original one

```
    SELECT TOP 1
            coalesce(Name1Unidecode, Name1, Name2Unidecode, Name2) AS Name
    FROM Persons 
    WHERE Season IS NOT NULL
            AND Season = @Season
            AND (Name2Code LIKE @NameCode + '%' OR Name1Code LIKE @NameCode + '%')
   ORDER BY update desc
```

I'm assuming that only one value is not `NULL` in attributes `Name1Unidecode`, `Name1`, `Name2Unidecode`, `Name2`. If it is not true, adjust it according to your data.

Moreover, if you have an indexes `Person(Season, Name2Code, update)` and `Person(Season, Name1Code, update)` then it should be really fast.

Comment: I think Name could be from Name 1 column also. I think query should be like have both name1 and name 2 and then one more comparison can be done to select actual name from both columns

Comment: @BlindSniper true, I did not noticed that he is using different names in those SQL.

Comment: This query can be used and output of this can be then compared with the namecode passed

Comment: @RadimBača thank you very much for your effort but returns not correct value. When clean TOP 1 limit from query every value shows different